# google.script.run in html UI doesn' t call server function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a couple of scripts that don't work anymore although I didn't make any change.
I don't spend a lot of time programming these last month so I didn't notice it right away...
Here is a simplified code that used to work and that doesn't, I can't figure out my error.
The HTML part is entirely built on server side since it's a very simple code (runs from a spreadsheet).

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = '<body style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt">';
  doc+='<select id="target" multiple style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt">';
  doc+='<option value="1">choice 1</option><option value="2">choice 2</option><option value="3">choice 3</option></select><br><br>';
  doc+='<input type="button" onClick="processJS()" style="background:#BFA;font-size:12pt" value="Validate"/>';
  doc+='<script>function processJS(){var e=document.getElementById("target");var values=Array.from(e.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);';
  doc+='console.log(JSON.stringify(values));google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){ window.alert(msg);google.script.host.close;}).processGSTest(values)};</script>';
  doc+='</body>';

  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc).setWidth(500).setHeight(250);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "test");
}

function processGSTest(values){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  return "processGSTest ok";
}
```

I get an error in JS console like this when I hit "validate" :

[image]

the HTML rendered window looks like this :

[image]

---

### EDIT

Following comments (thanks again) I've got a few more informations :

- when using another browser the scripts works fine
- when using chrome and adding an `withFailureHandler` it still fails with the same console message without handling the failure (Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Build officiel) (64 bits) on Mac OS High Sierra)
- when calling the same function from a custom menu the script works fine even in the same Chrome session

conclusion of this edit : I don't understand the issue :)

Comment: Can you check if you are running the V8 runtime or the legacy runtime?

Comment: I could confirm that when I tested your script, no error occurs with and without V8. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. So for example, when it creates new Spreadsheet and put your script in the script editor and run it, can you confirm whether the same error occurs? But, I'm not sure whether this leads to the solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: Shouldn't `google.script.host.close` be called? `google.script.host.close()`. Also try clearing browser cache,log out and login

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. As others said, I'd try clearing cache, and also trying with a new spreadsheet and with other accounts.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Trying another browser should have been my first reaction before asking here... sorry about that but I've never had any issue in chrome for years. It seems that it only me, I've tested on another computer and it works indeed.  I've cleared the cache, unlogged and relogged into my account, restarted my Mac a couple of times... nothing changes. So I finished the application using Firefox for now...and I keep digging.  If you have any other suggestions, I'm open ;) thanks again

Comment: Do you have two or more Google accounts logged in chrome? Maybe that's a issue

Comment: I'm almost always logged with two accounts, personal and professional. If this is the issue it should be an issue with all my script but it does not. It seems to be limited to a certain number but I can't find anything common to these...

Comment: Adding a `failureHandler` might help to catch the `uncaught`

Comment: Ah, good idea, I'll try and let you know the result.

Comment: the failure handler is not even caught

Comment: Maybe you should create a issue in the tracker

Comment: @TheMaster I was not handling the withFailure correctly, actually it does handle the error.

Comment: @Serge What was the error that was handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this post is about a very specific case that does not seem to be reproductible I answer it so it doesn't stay open indefinitely.
In the same time I'll post an issue report on the tracker.

Here is the script I use to show the issue.
The main function (myFunction) reports an error when called from the script editor but works when called from the menu...

This happens only on Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Build officiel) (64 bits) on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6, it works normally on Safari, Firefox and even Chrome on Windows 10.
*(It works also normally on the same version of Chrome under Mac OS 10.10.5 !! )*

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = '<body style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt">';
  doc+='<select id="target" multiple style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt">';
  doc+='<option value="1">choice 1</option><option value="2">choice 2</option><option value="3">choice 3</option></select><br><br>';
  doc+='<input type="button" onClick="processJS()" style="background:#BFA;font-size:12pt" value="Validate"/>';
  doc+='<script>function processJS(){var e=document.getElementById("target");var values=Array.from(e.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);';
  doc+='console.log(JSON.stringify(values));google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function err(){window.alert("error triggered by withFailureHandler");})';
  doc+='.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){ window.alert(msg);google.script.host.close();}).processGSTest(values)};</script>';
  doc+='</body>';

  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc).setWidth(500).setHeight(250);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "test");
}

function processGSTest(values){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  return "processGSTest ok";
}

function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "test", functionName: "myFunction"}]
  ss.addMenu("test",menuEntries);
}
```

I created a [shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxR7ZPPUecJOXD5mwWcUV89yHHIgPZLazs7DenWURvk/edit?usp=sharing) for anyone that would want to play with it (read only, make a copy to use)

Comment: reported on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155577903)